# Screenresolution utility in devops says successful but screen res is 640x480 - pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

So I have a pipeline in devops (On site hosted). One one agent the resolution remains at the tscon default even though the screen resolution utility in devops says it successfully set it to 1920*1080. Agent is not run as a service. Screenshots once this pipeline starts show the res as incorrect. I have another agent configured the same it it works fine. Any ideas? Its driving me crazy.
Any windows permissions that may prevent the resolution changing?

Yaml:

trigger:

- main

pool:
name: BDS-Automation-Agents
demands:

- Project -equals Serology

steps:

- task: VisualStudioTestPlatformInstaller@1
  inputs:
  packageFeedSelector: 'nugetOrg'
  versionSelector: 'specificVersion'
  testPlatformVersion: '17.x'
- task: InstallTestCompleteAdapter@1
  inputs:
  preferredExecutor: 'TC'
  installExecutor: false
  logsLevel: '0'
- task: ScreenResolutionUtility@1
  inputs:
  displaySettings: 'optimal'
- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
  testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
  testAssemblyVer2: 'AutomatedTests\AutomatedTests.pjs'
  searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
  vsTestVersion: '15.0'

Comment: Have you tried to change the resolution manually? And it is suggested to keep the screen alive during the ui test from being locked. Any update

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you could refer to this document for [Visible UI test via Sefl-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/ui-testing-considerations?view=azure-devops&tabs=mstest#visible-ui-testing-using-self-hosted-windows-agents).

> When configuring agents, `select 'No'` when prompted to `run as a service`. Subsequent steps then allow you to configure the agent with
> auto-logon. When your UI tests run, applications and browsers are
> launched in the context of the user specified in the auto-logon
> settings.

And you could also configure your `Screen Resolution Utility` task to the specific display setting.

```
steps:
- task: ScreenResolutionUtility@1
  inputs:
    displaySettings: 'specific'
    width: '1920'
    height: '1080'
```

Comment: I have done everything suggested on that page and specified a resolution. Still no change. Everything says it works, but it clearly doesn't. Any other ideas? There must be something on the physical agent blocking the resolution change. It feels permissions possible. User that the agent runs with is an admin on that box

Comment: @Endorium have you tried to reconfigure a selfhosted agent with `No` to `run as a service` and `Yes` to `auto-logon`?

Comment: It is set to auto login already. It is running interactively and not as a service